# How to show $\sum_{p\le x}\log p\left\lfloor\frac xp\right\rfloor = x\log x+O(x)$

Tags: number-theory

The question is in the title (note that $p$ is a prime number). I wrote it as
\begin{align}
\sum_{p\le x}\log p\left\lfloor\frac xp\right\rfloor &= \sum_{p\le x}\log p\sum_{n\le \frac{x}{p}}1\\
&=\sum_{np\le x}\log p\\
&=\sum_{n\le x}\sum_{p\le \frac{x}{n}}\log p
\end{align}
and then I couldn't proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log n! = \sum_{m\le n} \int_m^{m+1} \log m\ dt=
\sum_{m\le n} \int_m^{m+1}( \log t+O(1/t)) dt$$ $$=
 n\log n-n+O(\log n)$$
And
$$\log n! = \sum_{p^k\le n} \lfloor n/p^k \rfloor\log p=
\sum_{p\le n} \lfloor n/p \rfloor \log p\ \ +O(n\sum_{p^k,k\ge 2}\frac{\log p}{p^k})$$ $$=\sum_{p\le n} \lfloor n/p \rfloor \log p\ \ +O(n)$$

Comment: How does the last equality hold?

Comment: Which one? ${}{}$

Comment: When you took $O(n\sum_{p^k,k\ge 2}\frac{\log p}{p^k})=O(n)$.

Comment: $\sum_{p^k,k\ge 2} \frac{\log p}{p^k} \le 2 \sum_{p^k} \frac{\log p}{p^{2k}} \le 2\sum_{m\ge 1} m^{-3/2}$

Comment: Great answer, thank you!